# Build a visual studio project on a subset of files in a directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, svn, visual-c++, cmake

I would like to port my application from Linux to Windows. I'm trying to use visual studio to configure a project to build the Window application. The problem for me is that I only need a subset of files out my directory for Windows. But I would like to keep the integrity of the directory so that I don't need to checkout a subset of file to Windows. Does visual studio need the entire directory to be window files? For those who understand Window application development well, can you help me to understand:

1. Can I configure visual studio to build a project using a subset of the file from a directory?
2. If yes, how do I configure the project file? Any link to a tutorial would be really helpful.

Comment: Are you using CMake? In case yes, you just need to check the variable MSVC e create the list containing only the desired files, or exclude the ones you don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are couple of quick suggestions using Visual Studio

***Include/ Exclude :***
 If the number of file are minimum, then you could `include` or `exclude` files to a project manually.

1. You could add a directory to a project by copying the files to a folder under the .vcxproj(ur .<>proj) file.
2. Then select the project in the solution explorer and on the tool bar you would get an option `Show All Files`
3. Right click on the Folder or File and hit `Include In Project`. This will include the file/folder into your project.
4. You could `Exclude` any file that is already included in your project by, clicking the file and hit `Exclude From Project`.

***Remove From Compilation Only:***

1. Select the file in Solution Explorer and right click `Properties`
2. Under `Configuration Properties -> General -> Excluded From Build` set it to `Yes/No`